# why does sometimes IE11 does not render my css properly ?

Tags: html, css

My website works perfectly in chrome and Mozilla nothing breaks but in IE11 sometimes when i load the page it does not render properly like the buttons will be small and the inline links will look like overlapping and after i hover my mouse on top of it the css becomes normal, it becomes normal if i go to inspect element and change anything there.[this is what i am able to see sometimes only with IE``](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JLXN.png)

```css
 .site-links {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   display: inline-block;
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-right: 0px;
   border-radius: 0px;
 }
 .site-links li {
   display: inline-block;
 }
 .site-links li a {
   color: #000000;
 }
 .site-links li + li::before {
   color: #000000;
   content: "|";
   padding: 0 5px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="site-links">
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Privacy and Cookies Policy</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a>
  </li>
  <li class="show-f-link-t">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">PI</a>
  </li>
  <li class="show-f-link-t">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Report Adverse Event</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each browser reads css a little bit differently. In General, IE tends to break things up and does not naturally display your page the way you want, unless you develop it for IE.

I can offer two fixes for you.

1. Make sure you are using the latest css/html versions. With that said, make sure you are previewing your pages in updated browsers. Older browsers most likely will not support newer codes (Some of the older browsers have no support for CSS at all).

I have had several problems with IE and tend to stay away from it. Microsoft's latest IE browser, renamed Edge, has had major improvements from its IE series.

2. If all else fails, add CSS specific to IE. Adding code for IE specific will allow you to control the look and layout in an IE browser window. You do this using conditional comments.

Example:

```
body {
       color: red; /*All major browsers */
       color: green/9; /* IE Only */
}
```

You can go [here](http://For%20more%20info%20on%20browser%20specific%20css,%20you%20can%20go%20to%20this%20page) to learn more about browser specific css.

Comment: thank you matthew i will try and implement both your suggested fixes.

Comment: i tried but the problem looks different... its not that my css dosent loads, it does but after i hover over the buttons and footer or when i refresh.

Comment: So your CSS is only loading after you hover over an item?

Comment: Hey quite a late reply though sorry for this, but i fixed it. The problem was with the box-sizing.